# include methods from external php file in a class

Tags: php, oop

I have a class with own methods and on the other side a php file what contains external methods. From documentation is clear that inside of a class includeing external functions is not possible

How could I inculde this functions in my class. Making an another class and extend my first class it can not be an option.

Comment: In the file you want to include... are these actual methods on a class or are these free floating functions?

Comment: they are free floating functions

Comment: Don't. The point of a class is to encapsulate functionality and stop you from spreading related code across multiple files.

Comment: Yeah I tought so but I did not want to refactor all codes what I got

Comment: You'll wish you had, believe me.

Comment: This seems like a valid scenario. You are consuming third party code and you don't want to touch it - simply wrap the parts you need in an adapter class so the rest of your application doesn't have to know about it.

Comment: just tell me people why is so bad to use the workaround what Steve has been suggested. It seems a good workaround in my case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call external functions from a class, even if they are not enclosed in a class of their own:

Global.php

```
<?php
function doSomething() {
    return 'Hello';
}
?>
```

ExampleClass.php

```
<?php
include_once('Global.php');

class ExampleClass
{
    public function example() {
        return doSomething();
    }
}
?>
```

Although you probably wouldn't have the `include` in the actual class file.

Comment: That looks much too magical to me. But it kinda beats the point, as you would still have to declare wrappers for each function (or worse, use `__call()`).

Comment: It is not magical, it is called delegation. It isn't clear from the question whether the OP intends to simply call an external function to perform some task or wrap every function to disguise it as part of the class - I think you are assuming the latter, which could well be true - but you don't need to use `__call()` and there is no magic - it is just calling a function.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. All class definition, including methods and fields must be on the same file. You can't declare the same class in two different files.

Extending, or using **[traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)** (if you have PHP 5.4.x+), are your only options.